# Changes to runtime's LoadedPrograms between 1.17.6 and versions after in the ProgramTest context

Tags: testing, solana-program-test, program-test, runtime

Can someone summarize the changes to how [`LoadedPrograms`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a67767a03c394c9c0211b3167d7ddd4fb6e459f5/program-runtime/src/loaded_programs.rs#L619) work between version 1.17.6 and versions after? The changes have broken my `ProgramTest` setup and I would like to know if I can recreate it after upgrading my solana version.

In version 1.17.6, I would clone a program account from mainnet (e.g. the metaplex metadata program `metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s`), as well as its program data account (e.g. metaplex metadata program's is `PwDiXFxQsGra4sFFTT8r1QWRMd4vfumiWC1jfWNfdYT`), add both accounts to a `ProgramTest` with [`ProgramTest::add_account()`](https://docs.rs/solana-program-test/latest/solana_program_test/struct.ProgramTest.html#method.add_account), and then transactions calling the program would just work when using the created `BanksClient`.

However, in 1.17.28, the same transaction will trigger the [assertion failure in `LoadedPrograms::assign_program()`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a67767a03c394c9c0211b3167d7ddd4fb6e459f5/program-runtime/src/loaded_programs.rs#L702)

In 1.18, it would return [`TransactionError::InvalidProgramForExecution`](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/transaction/enum.TransactionError.html#variant.InvalidProgramForExecution)

Comment: This might be a bug in program-test. Can you create an issue with a minimal example that reproduces the problem? In general, the main difference with `LoadedPrograms` is that you need to wait an extra slot after deployment to use a program. So you might need to warp forward as a workaround

Comment: repro with it not working in 1.18.9 even after warping forward: https://github.com/billythedummy/loaded-programs-repro